# appending "../xx.txt" to the relative path does work in C++

Tags: c++, relative-path

I read some topics about relative path, but I've been wandering around them for hours without answer.
   The code is like this:

```
std::string path = "./Debug/";
path.append("../hi.txt/");
std::ifstream inFile(path);
std::string str;
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    inFile >> str;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "open failed" << std::endl;
}
```

This code will output:"open failed".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is hi.txt really a subdirectory? If it isn't then don't put a trailing slash after it,

Comment: I absolutely confirm that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put a `/` at the end of a path, it tells the system to execute it as a directory (i.e. list its contents). Since `hi.txt` is not a directory, you can't execute it as a directory and therefore it fails (assuming of course you didn't name a directory `hi.txt`).

To fix it: remove the `/`:

```
std::string path = "./Debug/" ;
path.append("../hi.txt") ;
```

Comment: by "execute" you mean "open"

Comment: @M.M Not necessarily. Symbolic links add funny business. I'm referring to how Linux calls directories (and symbolic links to directories) as having the execute flag set. If `/path/to/a` is a symbolic link to the directory `/path/to/b`, then `ls -la /path/to/a` will give you information about the symbolic link, but `ls -la /path/to/a/` will give you the same output as `ls -la /path/to/b/` because it "executes" that file as a filesystem-like thing and it resolves to the correct directory. But in simplistic terms, it is absolutely an "open" operation.